# Создание текстур в Libgdx, Android, Java

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Хочу создать List текстур.
Есть имя файла с кавычками:

```
String path = "\"badlogic.jpg\"";
```

Код выглядит так:

```
starTexture = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
```

Как передать стринговый path в new Texture:

```
starTexture = new Texture(path);
```

Выдает ошибку

```
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: "\core\assets\badlogic.jpg" (Internal)
```

Comment: Может быть не использовать в названии файла кавычки?

Comment: В new Texture надо передавать с кавычками. Мне нужно просто передать имя файла в кавычках.

Comment: Я говорю, что надо передавать не так "\"badlogic.jpg\"", а так "badlogic.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте применить:

```
new Texture(new FileHandle(new File(path)));
```

где `path` - указывает на путь где лежит `badlogic.jpg`